# How to fix "undefined is not an object"

Tags: react-native

if i use :
`{data[5]['key']}` no problem

but if i use :
`{data[this.state.cevap]['key']}`

I get error:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object`

[image]

```
<View>
<Text style={styles.ust_yazi}>Level {data[this.state.cevap]['key']}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Did you init the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check 
this.state.cevap or this.state exist?

Comment: state = {
    bolum:' ',
    cevap:3
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your state might have some value which is beyond the range of the indexes for data variable,therefore it is unable to obtain value, you can either make sure that the value of state variable is within the range or you can do this to avoid the error

```
<View>
      <Text style={styles.ust_yazi}>Level {data[this.state.cevap]?data[this.state.cevap]['key']:null}</Text>
</View>
```